# Pruebas unitarias con switch

Tags: java, junit

Estoy intentando crear unas pruebas unitarias a una de mis clases, pero no entiendo como realizarla, ya que no se parece a los ejemplos que he encontrado. Agradecería alguna directriz o ejemplo.

Se trata de realizar pruebas a una calculadora simple con javafx, pero tal vez mi método no están simple como un simple case y un return.

Este es el método original al que le quiero realizar las pruebas

```
public void evalOperador(String Operador){
    if(Digito){
        numOperandos ++;            
    }
    //Si ya tiene un numero almacenamos en la primera variable
    if(numOperandos == 1){
        Operando1 = Double.parseDouble(labPantalla.getText());
    }
    //Realizamos la misma operacion en la segunda variable
    if(numOperandos == 2){
        Operando2 = Double.parseDouble(labPantalla.getText());
        switch(this.Operador){
            case '+':
                Operando1 = Operando1 + Operando2;
                break;
            case '-':
                Operando1 = Operando1 - Operando2;
                break;
            case '*':
                Operando1 = Operando1 * Operando2;
                break;
            case '/':
                Operando1 = Operando1 / Operando2;
                break;
            case '=':
                Operando1 = Operando2;
                break;
        }
        labPantalla.setText(String.valueOf(Operando1));
        numOperandos=1;
        Punto = false;
    }
    Digito = false;
    this.Operador = Operador.charAt(0);
}
```

Este es algo de código con el que estoy ahora mismo

```
@BeforeClass
public static void inicio() {
    Operando1 = 10;
    Operando2 = 2;
}
/**
 * Test of evalOperador method, of class FXMLDocumentController.
 */
@Test
public void testEvalOperador() {
    FXMLDocumentController calc = new FXMLDocumentController();

    assertTrue(calc.evalOperador('+') == 12.0);
}
```

Comment: El problema no es el *switch*, el problema es la dependencia con *labPantalla*... ¿cómo piensas introducir los distintos valores a probar?

Comment: Ese es el problema, no se me ocurre como hacerlo, otra opción es no hacerle las pruebas, pero me las exigen y no sabría como justificarlo. Se lo preguntare al tutor y comento su respuesta. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Como escribí en el comentario, el problema no es el *switch* sino la dependencia de los datos que obtienes de *labPantalla*. Necesitas una forma de controlar qué datos se pasan (o incluso simplemente para asegurarte que se pasen datos y el test no se quede bloqueado esperando a que el usuario los introduzca).

Lo más sencillo es sencillamente pasar los datos por argumento y no depender de *labPantalla* para nada:

```
public void evalOperador(String Operador, String operando1, String operando2){
    ...
}
```

Esto tiene la ventaja de que hace tu método independiente de la presentación. Puedes usarlo en un programa que use la entrada por consola, por GUI, que saque los datos de una base de datos...

Si no puedes cambiar el código entonces lo que tienes que hacer es usar una implementación de *labPantalla* adecuada e inyectarla en tu clase:

```
public class LabPantallaTest extends LabPantalla {

   private String textoEntrada;
   private String textoSalida;

   public LabPantallaTest(String textoEntrada) {
      this.textoEntrada = textoEntrada;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return this.textoEntrada;
   }

   public void setText(String text) {
      this.textoSalida = text;
   }

   public String getTextoSalida() {
      return this.textoSalida;
   }
}
```

Antes de ejecutar el test creas una instancia de *LabPantallaTest* y la **inyectas** en tu clase de forma que se use ésa; después del test invocas a *getTextoSalida()* para obtener el resultado y comprobar si es el esperado.

Este tipo de objetos (que simulan para un test una dependencia) se llaman *mockups*. Pueden hacerse complicados muy rápidamente (por ejemplo si quieres que cada vez que se llama a *getText()* devuelva un valor distinto); hay librerías como [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito) o [jmockit](/questions/tagged/jmockit) que simplifican su creación, describiendo su comportamiento en vez de teniendo que programarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Al final me ayudo tu repsuesta y lo solucione de esta forma (Muchas gracias):

public class FXMLDocumentControllerTest {

```
public FXMLDocumentControllerTest() {
}

static double Operando1;
static double Operando2;
static char Operador;
static boolean Digito;
static int numOperandos;

@BeforeClass
public static void inicio() {
    Operando1 = 10;
    Operando2 = 2;
    Operador = '-';
    Digito = false;
    numOperandos = 2;
}
/**
 * Test of evalOperador method, of class FXMLDocumentController.
 */
@Test
public void testEvalOperador() {
    //Realizamos la misma operacion en la segunda variable
    if(numOperandos == 2){
        switch(this.Operador){
            case '+':
                Operando1 = Operando1 + Operando2;
                break;
            case '-':
                Operando1 = Operando1 - Operando2;
                break;
            case '*':
                Operando1 = Operando1 * Operando2;
                break;
            case '/':
                Operando1 = Operando1 / Operando2;
                break;
            case '=':
                Operando1 = Operando2;
                break;
        }
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(false, Operando1==12);
}
```

}